# Override Material UI CssBaseline on a per-page basis (specifically the background color)

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I'm using the `ThemeProvider` and `CssBaseline` in my `_app.js` file. It's pulling in the background color from the theme as expected.

However, on some pages, I want to override the the body background color. I *was* able to achieve this by wrapping my page components in a different theme and adding `CssBaseline` as a child but it doesn't seem like the *right* way to do it since I'm already using `CssBaseline` at the app level.

Is there a better way to do this or am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a little tricky but in css file use !important to overwrite the theme or frameworks file or use inline css